# Why I'm getting this error when displaying an image in customtkinter?

Tags: python, customtkinter

I'm trying to display an image from a specific folder, but the error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist" is showing. I have verified the image path, and it's correct.

This is a project where many nested functions are called. I suppose this may be the cause of the error, since I have tried this isolated function in another app and it's working properly.

```
def display_image(csv_file_name, df, frame):
    # Create image path
    image_path = current_folder_path + '/' + csv_file_name + '.png'
    # Create image widget
    my_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(image_path), size=(25, 25))
    # Create label to display image
    image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, text="", image=my_image)
    image_label.pack()
```

_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If adding (**outside** of your function, in the global scope) a list variable such as `picsList = []`, then inside your function doing `picsList.append(my_image)` fixes your problem, then this question will be a duplicate of the one linked above

Comment: Possibly you've created more than one instance of `Tk()`/`CTk()`.  Each image object is tied to one instance, and won't work with widgets that are part of a different instance.  If this is the problem, use `Toplevel()` (or whatever the customtkinter equivalent is) to create additional windows.

Comment: Silly question, but have you imported an image library like Pillow? `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you've created more than one instance of Tk()/CTk(). Each image object is tied to one instance, and won't work with widgets that are part of a different instance. If this is the problem, use Toplevel() (or whatever the customtkinter equivalent is) to create additional windows. – jasonharper

*This was the reason of the error. I tried to use a class designed for displaying toplevel windows in customtkinter and it worked. Thanks to jasonharper.